# Getting error when I use same version dependencies in gradle

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, build.gradle

I'm confused on why this isn't working because my previous versions worked but they were a lower version:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
```

However, when I tried to upgrade to a newer version I get the error in this image:

[image]

And it says that I am mixing versions but I'm not, since I put them all the same.

```
All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 15.1.0, 15.0.2, 15.0.1, 15.0.0. Examples include `com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:15.1.0` and `com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:15.0.2`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from May 2018:

> Firebase Android SDKs now have independent version numbers, allowing for more frequent, flexible updates.

According to [this](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android), please change the following lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
```

And according to [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), please change the following line of code:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
```

And according to [this](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android), please change the following line of code:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
```

Please also add the following dependecy, which is now mandatory:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
```

Also be sure to use also the latest version for Google play services in your top level build.gradle file:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

Comment: It says build successful, however there's a red line under implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2' saying the same error. All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 17.0.1, 17.0.0, 16.2.1, 16.0.3, 16.0.2, 16.0.1, 16.0.0, 15.1.0, 15.0.1. Examples include `com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:17.0.1` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:17.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

change dependency in Project gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}
```

and in module

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
```